# How to make a conditional SQL statement

Tags: mysql, conditional-statements

I want to make a conditional SQL. I have one table "`users`" and it has two columns `(id, status)`

**I need to search for users IDs based on their status.**

For example : 
Every 5 seconds I am querying from the database (by AJAX) as per the below description:

Let us say that I have the below results on my wall (on html):

```
id1: 1
status2: "A"

id2: 2
status2: "B"
```

**I need to get IDs from table "users" but exclude the IDs from database if their status haven't changed on my wall.**

So the algorithm should be:

```
Get all IDs from table "users" but exclude the IDs (1,2) from database 
(if and only if) their status = ("A", "B").
```

Simply, I need to retrieve all IDs including the IDs (1,2). But for the IDs (1,2): I need to retrieve them in case their corresponding statuses are NOT EQUAL ("A", "B") respectively.

But for IDs other than (1,2) like (3,4,5,...), I need to retrieve them without any condition.

I would greatly appreciate if the solution provides an excellent performance when the database records are huge and the check every 5 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want something like this:

```
WHERE (id IN (1, 2) AND status NOT IN ('A', 'B'))
   OR (id NOT IN (1, 2))
```

This can be boiled down to the shorter (but, I think, less readable):

```
WHERE id NOT IN (1, 2) OR status NOT IN ('A', 'B')
```

Answer (score 0):

Is that what you are looking for:

```
SELECT id FROM table1 WHERE id NOT IN
(SELECT id FROM table1 WHERE id IN (1,2) AND status IN ('A','B'))
```